# CodeBlocks MinGW version not finding files, have to manually include in linker

Tags: c++, windows, linker

Windows 7 64-bit running Code:Blocks 13+ MinGW version 32-bit.

Compiling code from "Tricks of the Windows Game Programing Gurus", specifically demo 3_4.

So here is the issue, which I know is specifically a Code::Blocks issue, but I figure there are more Code::Blocks people here than at the program's forums.

I installed Code:Blocks 13.12 MinGW version, I think I kept everything at the defaults. I load up my demo 3_4 project, build in Release mode and I get an error, "undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'". I Google around, and find advice that says I have to include the lwinmm into the project/linker settings.

However, inside the Code::Blocks install folder there is an include folder which contains libwinmm.a. I can be lazy, and just add the entire frikkin' list of library files, and if I do it will compile and run in Release mode. Without doing that it will only compile and run in Debug mode.

Now it seems to me that if I install Code::Blocks MinGW version that Code::Blocks ought to know where these stinking library files are and that I should not have to add them. So how do I set this up? What option do I use, box do I check, path do I set, etc.? How do I get Code::Blocks to stop being a lazy POS and find the stuff that is right there in its own install directory without having to add things manually to the linker list?

This problem also occurs with other code that I build. Some runs in Debug, some in Release, a few in both. Why is that? Did I install Code::Blocks incorrectly, or miss some setting somewhere?

I appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the libraries you need. You cannot expect the linker to go looking for them. That's part of the design of the C/C++ linking mechanism. If the linker went hunting for libraries you would not be able to control what was in your program.

IDEs on Windows will typically include the most commonly used libraries (kernel32.lib, user32.lib etc.) in their default projects. But for less widely used libraries, you have to add them manually.